# conditional probability question Given bayesian network could not understand solution given

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

Given Bayesian network [image: A] 
can't understand the two last steps in [image: B] 
why the p(C=c|E=e,~H) can get out of the e sum? 
and why sum p(E=e|A,S,~H) and sum p(C=c|E=e,~H) and been neglected? 
Thank for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why the $p(C=c\mid E=e,\neg H)$ can get out of the $e$ sum?

It's not - it's just loose notation in that answer. Adding extra parentheses would be clearer, (though it should be understood by the appearance of $e$ in the inner sum) making the denominator in Line (4) read:

$$P(A)P(S)P(\neg H)\sum_e{[P(E=e\mid A,S,\neg H) \sum_c{P(C=c\mid E=e,\neg H)} ]}.$$

> why $\sum p(E=e|A,S,\neg H)$ and $\sum p(C=c|E=e,\neg H)$ have been neglected?

Because $\sum_c p(C=c|E=e,\neg H) = 1$ (because we're summing over all possible values of $C$).

Similarly, $\sum_e p(E=e|A,S,\neg H) = 1$ (because we're summing over all possible values of $E$).